# Mathematical parser

Tags: code-golf, math, number

## Challenge :

Given a string representing a mathematical expression return the result

---

## Input :

A string representing a mathematical expression : `'1 + 2 - 3 * (2/3 * 1)'`.

## Output :

The result after performing all operations.

---

## Operators :

### Possible operators

```
+     ---> plus
-     ---> minus
*     ---> multiplication
/     ---> division
(     ---> opening parenthesis 
)     ---> closing parenthesis
```

### operator precedence :

Operators are always evaluated from `left-to-right` going `from here ---> there`, and `* and /` must be evaluated before `+ and -`

Parenthesis take precedence over everything else and must be completed before all.

### Parenthesis :

You should be able to support multiple(nested) levels of parenthesis.

e.g :

```
 1 - ( 2 * ( 3 / 9 + ( 2 * 6 ) ) )
```

### White space :

Whitespace doesn't matter, you can have whitespace between operators or you can't (**Consistency is required though**)

---

## Note :

- Given input will always be valid. It will consist of nothing except

  - Numbers (`0-9`) of arbitary length
  - operators (`+ , - , * , /`)
  - parenthesis (`( / )`) nested
  - white space (`optional with consistency`)
- Use of `eval` and `Function` or their equivalent counter-parts in any language is forbidden
- using built-in functions designed specifically for this is also forbidden
- all standard loopholes are forbidden by default.
- You need to support floats to a reasonably high value (depending on the language) but after that integers will work. alternately after that floating point error (if reasonable) will be acceptable.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

---

## Examples :

```
 1 + 2 * 3              ---> 7
 10 * 2 / (2 - 3) * 2   ---> -10 (expression is (2*10) / ((2-3)*2) => 20/-2
 1-(2*(3/9+(2*6)-3))    ---> -53/3 (3/9 is the fraction and not the whole)
 -1 * --10              ---> -10 (support for unary minus)
```

---

Comment: Is unary minus one of the operations ?

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun : Yep

Comment: Should floating point numbers also be supported or only integer is okay ?

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun : supported till your language can hold them after the floating point error is acceptable.

Comment: Can we output floating point numbers instead of fractions?

Comment: @ovs : You can output that way

Comment: Looking at your final example, to maintain white space 'consistency' , shouldn't the unary minus be expressed as "- 1 * - - 10"? And further to that, considering you use two unary minus signs in a row, as in your example, can you also use a unary plus sign, "+1" for example, and if so can you arbitrarily mix unary signs: "-+1*+--+10"?

Comment: **Mathematica, 0 bytes**

Comment: @StanStrum haha, nice one (but you would still need something like `#&`, which costs 2 bytes). But I think that's invalid because it relies on Mathematica's internal auto-**eval**uation.

Comment: Shouldn't your second example equal `-40` instead of `-10`?

Comment: "White space consistency": does this mean we can choose whether we allow whitespace or not? Or does it mean that an input may contain whitespace, and if it does, it is consistent?

Comment: Also, may I suggest changing the title to something like "Arithmetic interpreter", since this is really more than just a parser?

Comment: I'm confused by your second example. Since `*` and `/` have the same precedence, and we go left to right, shouldn't it be `((2*10)/-1)*2`?